# Blender.sx font issues on Ubuntu

Tags: bug, user-interface

Recently, and I cannot pin point a date, in this website and its meta all fonts are bold-faced and its rather unpleasant to the eye. I've seen this on two separate machines (both with Firefox though) and using clean profiles.

At home, using OSX and same version of Firefox it is fine but on Ubuntu I have this issue. Other sister websites for stackexchange network are all fine. Below are some screenshots.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible you have any extensions/userchrome stylesheets which could be doing this? If you start firefox with a fresh profile, does this still happen?

Comment: @gandalf3, I did restart my firefox in safe mode but still everything is bold-faced. However, I checked it with my colleagues machine (FF@Ubuntu) and it seems fine. It seems there is some strange problem with me only... I guess you could close the question.